# sending data from Quilljs to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, wysiwyg, quill

How do I send data from Quilljs(frontend) to node.js(backend). I try to find all example, but there's nothing that related to backend. I've read information from Quilljs's doc but I still don't really get it, or could you guys explain me the concept.

Below code is what I really think about, but I don't know how to got data from frontend.

Fontend

```
<form action="p_comment" method="post">
  <div id="editor">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

Backend

```
router.post('/p_comment', function(req, res, next) {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quill uses a JSON format called [Delta](https://quilljs.com/docs/delta/) to represent its content.
You case call [getContents](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getcontents) to get the current Delta.
There is an [example](https://quilljs.com/playground/#form-submit) in the docs how to use it to send the Delta to the server.

You can also get the raw HTML manually by calling quill.root.innerHTML or querySelector('ql-editor').innerHTML. You can't trust the HTML from the client and you'll need to sanitize it.